# tableView not refreshing

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview

I am new to programming and currently building an app where I collect data from Firebase.

I thought it would be nice to implement this refreshing animation, when the view is pulled down. Now I have the problem that nothing gets refreshed at all (it was working fine in the beginning). Also every time the app launches the tableView is empty at first and when you make the pushdown it reloads, but wrong.

I am really struggling. Can anyone see anything wrong in my code?

```
class ViewController: BaseViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var newsfeedTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    private let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    var posts = [String]()
    var timeRef = [String]()
    var userRef = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addSlideMenuButton()
        setupTableView()

        ref = Database.database().reference()

        ref.child("posts").observe( .childAdded, with: { snapshot in

            let newPost = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let post_title:String = newPost!["post_title"] as? String ?? "error"

            let newPostTime = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let post_time:String = newPostTime!["post_time"] as? String ?? "error collecting timestamp"

            let newPostUser = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let post_user:String = newPostUser!["post_user"] as? String ?? "Team"

            self.posts.insert(post_title, at: 0)
            self.timeRef.insert(post_time, at: 0)
            self.userRef.insert(post_user, at: 0)

            self.newsfeedTableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

    private func setupTableView() {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            newsfeedTableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
        } else {
            newsfeedTableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
        }
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshNewsFeedTableView(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    @objc private func refreshNewsFeedTableView(_ sender: Any) {

        //self.refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
        self.newsfeedTableView.reloadData()
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! NewsfeedCell

        cell.customTextLabel?.text = posts[indexPath.row]
        cell.customTimeLabel?.text = timeRef[indexPath.row]
        cell.customNameLabel?.text = userRef[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
    }

    class NewsfeedCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var customTextLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var customNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var customTimeLabel: UILabel!

    }
```

Comment: Are the database operations async? Do you need to use `dispatchQueue.main.async{ }` when you reload the tableview to do it on the correct thread?

Comment: @TommyBs callback of firebase  is in main thread by default

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
@objc private func refreshNewsFeedTableView(_ sender: Any)
```

you don't do any API requests to get the data then reload the table and end refreshing , and since you use observe here

```
ref.child("posts").observe( .childAdded, with: { snapshot in
```

then you'll get any new data ,  if you need to implement the refresh then insert all database code inside a function and replace `observe` with `observeSingleEvent` and call it from `viewDidLoad` and from the refresh selector method

```
ref.child("posts").observeSingleEvent( .value, with: { snapshot in
```

Note with the suggested approach you will get all the childs at a time so don't forget to clean the array inside the callback of `observeSingleEvent` to avoid duplicating values , also consider making one dataSource array instead of 3 here

```
 self.posts.insert(post_title, at: 0)
 self.timeRef.insert(post_time, at: 0)
 self.userRef.insert(post_user, at: 0)
```

probably with creating a model

```
struct Item {
  let post:String
  let time:String
  let user:String
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only problem I can see in the code is, you are using .childAdded to observe events from firebase but according to firebase document:

> The **child_added** event is typically used when retrieving a list of
>   items from the database. Unlike value which returns the entire
>   contents of the location, **child_added** is triggered once for each
>   existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the
>   specified path. The event callback is passed a snapshot containing the
>   new child's data. For ordering purposes, it is also passed a second
>   argument containing the key of the previous child.

So, if you want to receive all the data of any particular node, you need to use **value** event but not **child_added** as stated here:

> The **value** event is used to read a static snapshot of the contents
>   at a given database path, as they existed at the time of the read
>   event. It is triggered once with the initial data and again every time
>   the data changes. The event callback is passed a snapshot containing
>   all data at that location, including child data. In the code example
>   above, value returned all of the blog posts in your app. Everytime a
>   new blog post is added, the callback function will return all of the
>   posts.

Answer (score 0):

Reload UItableView in DispatchQueue.main, try this code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addSlideMenuButton()
        setupTableView()

        ref = Database.database().reference()

        ref.child("posts").observe( .childAdded, with: { snapshot in

            let newPost = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let post_title:String = newPost!["post_title"] as? String ?? "error"

            let newPostTime = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let post_time:String = newPostTime!["post_time"] as? String ?? "error collecting timestamp"

            let newPostUser = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let post_user:String = newPostUser!["post_user"] as? String ?? "Team"

            self.posts.insert(post_title, at: 0)
            self.timeRef.insert(post_time, at: 0)


            self.userRef.insert(post_user, at: 0)
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.newsfeedTableView.reloadData()
            }

        })
    }
```

Comment: Nothing has changed :(